# What is the algorithm that is used to generate the numbers in this table and what will be the output for N = 6?

Tags: algorithm

What is the algorithm that is used to generate the numbers in this table and what will be the output for N = 6?

The Table is here:

[image]

Comment: You haven't posted a table and I'm not sure why this is tagged C, but the meta-answer to this question is to look up what you have on https://oeis.org/

Comment: `First N even numbers starting from 0` followed by `N consecutive positive integers starting from N`...

Comment: Please do not post images.  Rather copy past the table into the question as text

Answer (score 3):

The first n even numbers including 0 and all integers from n to n+n-1

Output for n = 6 :

```
  0 2 4 6 8 10 6 7 8 9 10 11
```

Comment: I got the same result on a duplicate question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68599052/ans-with-explation-please) except it was first N even numbers starting at zero, followed by N consecutive numbers starting with N (same as yours, just worded differently).

Answer (score 2):

**C Code Snipplet:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  printf("Number Sequence Sample \n");
  int limit = 6;

    for(int i= 0; i <= limit; i++){
      printf ("[ %d ] ", i);

        if(i == 0){
         printf ("%s \n","");
          continue;
        }

    for(int j=0; j <=((i*2)-1); j++){
        if( j % 2 == 0){
          printf ("%d ",j);
        }  
    }

    for(int k=i; k <=((i*2)-1); k++){
      printf ("%d ",k);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
Number Sequence Sample
[ 0 ]
[ 1 ] 0 1
[ 2 ] 0 2 2 3
[ 3 ] 0 2 4 3 4 5
[ 4 ] 0 2 4 6 4 5 6 7
[ 5 ] 0 2 4 6 8 5 6 7 8 9
[ 6 ] 0 2 4 6 8 10 6 7 8 9 10 11
```